# C++ multiple interfaces inheritance and static_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, multiple-inheritance

In the following code:

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd87d91c309adea)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

struct IView {
    virtual void setOnClick() = 0;
};
struct ITextView : IView {
    virtual void setText() = 0;
};
struct IButton : ITextView {
    virtual void setRadius() = 0;
};

struct View : IView {
    int i = 1;
    virtual void setOnClick() override {
        std::cout << "setting OnClick! i: " << i << std::endl;
    };
};

/// Works as is
/// But if make "TextView : View, ITextView" - have segfault on the run
struct TextView : ITextView, View {
    int j = 2;
    virtual void setText() override {
        std::cout << "setting text! i: " << i << " j: " << j << std::endl;
    };

    // forward IView
    virtual void setOnClick() override {
        View::setOnClick();
    }
};


int main() {
    TextView tv;

    void* ptr = &tv;    // I need to pass raw pointer, and then restore "interface" from it

    ITextView* itv = static_cast<ITextView*>(ptr);  // I don't need safety checks here
    itv->setOnClick();
    itv->setText();

    return 0;
}
```

If I change `TextView`s inheritance order I'll have segfault on `itv->setText();` call.

Why is it important? Can I use `static_cast` here, or I have UB here? As I understand `dynamic_cast` only required with virtual inheritance, and this, as I can tell, not that case.

Comment: Try `ITextView* itv = &tv; void* ptr = itv;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it stands, you convert implicitly from `TextView*` to `void*`, then explicitly from `void*` to `ITextView*`. These conversions do not perform any pointer adjustment when casting from/to `void*`, so you end up with a pointer of type `ITextView*` which actually points to a `TextView` (not to its `ITextView` subobject!): undefined behaviour ensues.

The solution is to take care of *always* using the exact same type on both "sides" of the `void*`:

```
TextView tv;

void* ptr = static_cast<ITextView*>(&tv); // Adjust, then convert to void*

ITextView* itv = static_cast<ITextView*>(ptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pointers to different class "slices" are different.

So when you tranport via void *, you need to

```
void * ptr = static_cast<ITextView *>(&tv);
...
ITextView* itv = static_cast<ITextView*>(ptr)
```

---

Note that you have two "instances" of IView in your base class hierarchy:

```
TextView  <- ITextView <- ... <- IView
          \- View <- IView
```

There is virtual inheritance to turn that into a "diamond": [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

Comment: In OP's example, is this UB? No segfault for me, which would indicate that

Comment: @Fureeish - Yes, it's UB. Doesn't have to crash to be any more or less UB.

Comment: Worth nothing that the static cast is doing something different in each line.

Comment: About virtual inheritance. 1) I need to pass raw pointer around. Can't do `dynamic_cast` from `void*` 2) Even If I will static_cast void* to let's say `IView `, and then do dynamic_cast, dynamic cast is extremely costly. Right?

Comment: @tower120: 1) using a raw pointer: there's no need to use `dynamic_cast`. Just make that T1=T2 when casting T1 * -> void * -> T2*.  2) Yes, dynamic_cast can be costly at least in the general case (multiple inheritance usually...)   3) virtual inheritance (or rather the lack thereof) is a completely separate problem: as is, there are two ways to cast to `IView`, which would be different, static_cast from `IView` to `View` is ambigous, and not providing a setOnClick-Implementation in View can create puzzling behavior.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to make T1=T2, then I need to use most base interface `IView`. And then when I will restore from `void*` I get `IView`. If I will need `IButton`, I'll have to `dynamic_cast` it from `IView`. Right?

Comment: ahhh.. for the general case, and if you don't know what kind of IView you are getting: YES! And that's exactly where having two IView's in your base class becomes a problem. --- dynamic_cast performance isn't too bad (supposedly ~30x reinterpret_cast worst case), not good for high-frequency trading or inner game loops. In suhc a case, I'd probably roll my own "QueryInterface" -like mechanism

Comment: dynamic_cast performance: https://tinodidriksen.com/2010/04/cpp-dynamic-cast-performance/

Comment: I expect relatively high interface inheritance level (around 6) - so it should be a problem... (According to that blog it will be higher then mutex lock-unlock). If only I could leave interfaces non-virtual... Or forward as I forward in more general way.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you are doing a `static_cast` to a different type passing by a `void*` which hides the actual type to the compiler.

What I mean is that:

```
TextView tv;
ITextView* itv = static_cast<ITextView*>(&tv);
```

this is safe, you are explicitly converting to an parent type.

```
TextView tv;
void* ptr = &tv;
ITextView* itv = static_cast<ITextView*>(ptr);
```

Here the compiler doesn't know the actual type of `ptr` and consider it as a `ITextView*`, so it not able to adjust the pointer to the correct subpart of an object (it is worth noticing that this may seem to work because `ITextView` doesn't have any member variables). This is related in how inheritance is implemented under the hood, think about:

```
---------------------
| VTable A | Type A |
---------------------

---------------------
| VTable B | Type B |
---------------------

-----------------------------------------
| VTable AB | Type A | Type B | Type AB |
-----------------------------------------
```

Suppose this is the memory layout for

```
class A { /* members */ };
class B { /* members */ };
class AB : public A, public B { /* members */ };
```

Now this is clear that if you have the address to an `AB` and you cast it to an `B*` without letting the compiler know that it was an `AB` then the compiler is not able to point to the correct **Type B** part, which resides after **Type A** slice. This would have been possible to know only by knowing that it was an `AB` in the first place.